# Existence of context-free grammar over {0,1} alphabet

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

Is there a context-free grammar $G$ for which $L(G) = \lbrace w \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace^{*} : \exists a,b \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace^{*} \wedge w = aba \wedge |a| = |b| \rbrace$?

This question could be very hard because my lacturer can't solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intersect the language with $0^*10^*10^*1$. What do you get?